# Quiero que me devuelva el nombre de la ciudad solo una vez aunque la misma ciudad aparezca mas de una vez en la base de datos

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Tengo un problema porque cuando el usuario busca una ciudad quiero que si tengo dos veces el nombre de la ciudad en la base de datos, quiero que le devuelva el nombre de la ciudad solo una vez…

Habia pensado hacerlo con HashSet, pero no me esta saliendo. Me sigue devolviendo el nombre de la ciudad mas de una vez aunque tenga la misma ciudad mas de una vez. Sera una cosa sencilla como un for Loop o algo asi para hacerlo funcionar, pero no consigo hacerlo. Alguine me puede decir la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Que el nombre de la ciudad se me devuelva una vez aunque tenga esa misma ciudad mas de una vez...

Como puedo hacerlo?

```
public class SearchCityFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Post> mPostList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CityAdapter mCityAdapter;

    private EditText mSearchBar;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_city, container, false);

        mRelativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_11);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        mPostList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCityAdapter = new CityAdapter(getContext(), mPostList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCityAdapter);

        mSearchBar = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        mSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                searchCity(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchCity(String s) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("city").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPostList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        mPostList.clear();
                        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPostList.add(post);
                        readCity();
                    }
                }

                mCityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readCity() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mSearchBar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mPostList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        mPostList.add(post);
                    }

                    mCityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            mActivity = (Activity) context;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma correcta seria usar el HashMap o HashSet pero sobreescribiendo el metodo equals y el hashcode en el objecto Post

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof Post) {
    Post p = (Post) o;
    return this.name.equals(p.name);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return (int)(Math.random()*1000);
}
```

o en todo caso podrias realizar un for dentro de otro (n*n)

```
boolean b = true;
for (Post m_post : mPostList) {
  if(m_post.name.equals(post.name){
    b = false;
    break;
  }
}

if(b) mPostList.add(post);
```

Comment: El segundo metodo me ha ganado. Gracias tio. Te lo agradezco mucho!

Comment: Un pregunta, cual es la diferencia entre los dos metodos. He hecho el segundo y me ha funcionado de maravilla, pero el primero tiene algo que el segundo no tenga? O en principio ambos deberian funcionar igual de bien?

Comment: anteriormente mencionaste que usaste HashSet pero no te funciono, esto se debe a que no estaba sobreescritos dichos metodos(equals, hashcode), al final HashSet no realizaba correctamente la comparacion por eso te seguia apareciendo doble

Comment: Jussto tio, lo hice asi tal cual. Intente a hacerlo con HashSet, pero me seguia saliendo doble. Pues nada, gracias por la ayuda!